# C++ Visual Studio 2010 how to use a char type variable in different functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, char

I'm having a problem regarding a char type variable in my program.
I don't post the code because it is too long but this is roughly what I want to do:

```
#include ...

char path[100];

int main()
{
    char path[100] = "C:/......";

    [...]

    out = function();
}

int function()
{
    [...]
    imwrite(path,image);
    [...]

}
```

The problem is that my path variable seems to be lost somehow because if I try cout < < path before imwrite in function it doesen't print anything as if path was empty.

What should I do forbeing able to access my path variable in function?

Comment: if this is c++, you should be using std::string for your strings.

Comment: global `path` and the one you initialize in `main` are different variables. Read a decent book on C programming before you go any further

Comment: @aleguna I would not add C to the tags. It does looks like C code, but @alvinleetya does mention trying `cout`.

Comment: @crashmstr The problem is that when using string I cant use strcat_s and I'm doing modifications on these strings in main and function

Comment: @alvinleetya, with `std::string`, why would you need `strcat`? Just use the `+` operator to add, `=` to assign. When you need to pass a const character pointer (C style string), use `.c_str()`.

Comment: @alvinleetya, to concatenate `std::string`s you can simply use `+` :  `std::string s = s1+s2` and not bother about memory allocation

Comment: @crashmstr Thanks, I forgot about that! 
I've also noticed that the mkdir function to creat a directory only take a char as input. Is there an equivalent for strings?

Comment: You can get a `const char*` from a `std::string` using `std::string::c_str()`

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the `path` variable within the scope of your main function, as well as in the global scope.

In `main()` you have a new declaration of `path`:

```
char path[100] = "...";
```

This effectively gives you two variables with the same name, but in different scopes.  If you access `path` from within the `main` method, it will access the locally-scoped variable.

If you wish to keep it this way, and remove the globally-scoped `path` variable, you could redeclare your function to:

```
int function(char* p_path)
{
    imwrite(p_path, image);
}
```

and pass the value as a parameter from main:

```
char path[100] = "...";
...
function(path);
```

As an aside, you could force access of the globally-scoped variable from within the main method by referencing `::path`, which specifies the global namespace. But that's another story.

Comment: No, you're not. It's fine to declare a variable multiple times, but these are two definitions. And they define two variables. "Definition" = "Here is ..."; "declaration" = "there is ..."

Comment: That's what I meant by re-declaring. I added information about the scope of the two declarations.

Comment: You're still confusing the terms "definition" and "declaration". A second declaration would NOT give you two variables. A second definition DOES.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining a global variable `path` (in global scope) and a local variable `path` in `main()`. This means that inside `main()`, `path` refers to the local one, while in `function()`, it refers to the global one.

If the path is hardcoded (as in the example you gave), you can do this:

```
#include ...

char path[100] = "C:/......";

int main()
{
    [...]

    out = function();
}
```

If the path needs to be computed, do this instead:

```
#include ...

char path[100];

int main()
{
    [...]
    std::copy(computedPathValue, computedPathValue + computedPathLength + 1, path);

    out = function();
}
```

Of course, the best would be to have `std::string path` instead of a `char[100]`.